# simplebar scroll remove overflow hidden option

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using scrollbar from below location. It is working fine. 
https://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/

Please see my fiddle. In my demo i have displayed the list on video/image. If i click the video or image it should be enlarge. I was achieved by css. Click the first image it should be enlarged. But the enlarged video or image will be hidden. I want the image or video should be overlap from the scrollbar also push the below element. Is this possible?
http://jsfiddle.net/akn1r638/

```
$(".viewenlarge").click(function(){
    $(".video").addClass("expand");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/akn1r638/27/

```js
$(".video").click(function(){
     $(this).css("width","250px");
     $(".content").css("margin-top", "20px");
     $(".image").css("margin-top", "20px");
     
});
```

```css
.demo1 {
  height:  250px;
  width: 250px;
}



.left-panel {
  width: 250px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.video{
  background-image:url('https://www.fujifilmusa.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x20/sample_images/img/index/pic_09.jpg');
  
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-panel">

<div class="demo1" data-simplebar>
<div >

        <h2>Scroll me!</h2>
        <p class="video viewenlarge"></p>
 <p class="image"><img src= "https://www.fujifilmusa.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x20/sample_images/img/index/pic_08.jpg"></p>        <p class="content">Some more content</p>
        <p class="odd">Some content</p>
        <p>Some more content</p>
        <p class="odd">Some content</p>
        <p>Some more content</p>
        <p class="odd">Scroll me!</p>
              hey!
              </div>
      </div>
            </div>
```

Kindly check the updated fiddle, a little bit of tinkering should get you there.